# when call the class convolution, it say error

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

gdd.forward(x) call error,  but  why?

This code uses imcol to implement the convolution layer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PycharmProjects/untitled2/kk.py", line 61, in <module>
    gdd.forward(x)
  File "E:/PycharmProjects/untitled2/kk.py", line 46, in forward
    FN,C,FH,FW=self.W.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)



import numpy as np

class Convolution:
  # 卷积核大小
    def __init__(self,W,b,stride=1,pad=0):
        self.W = W
        self.b = b
        self.stride = stride
        self.pad = pad
    def forward(self,x):
        FN,C,FH,FW=self.W.shape
        N,C,H,W = x.shape
        out_h = int(1+(H+ 2*self.pad - FH) / self.stride)
        out_w = int(1+(W + 2*self.pad -FW) / self.stride)


e = np.array([[2,0,1],[0,1,2],[1,0,2]])
x = np.array([[1,2,3,0],[0,1,2,3],[3,0,1,2],[2,3,0,1]])
gdd = Convolution(e,3,1,0)
gdd.forward(x)
```

Comment: What error? Please include the exact error message as text (not an image/screenshot!), and on which line it occurred and what the most relevant input data was when the error message appeared

Answer (score 0):

not enough value to unpack means that there are 2 outputs, but you are expecting 4:

```
FN,C,FH,FW=self.W.shape
```

just get rid of 2 of them and you are good to go :)

BTW I'm assuming you speak Chinese? 我说中文， 不懂可以用中文问一下